# Реализация many to many без использования ORM на Java

Tags: java, jdbc

Всем привет! Впервые тут задаю вопрос, так что слишком строго не судите, попытаюсь корректно объяснить :)
Нужно реализовать связь многие ко многим без использования ORM.

Есть сущность Сериал, которая может хранить в себе список нескольких жанров

```java
public class Serial{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Set<Genre> genres;

}
```

Жанр в свою очередь хранит список сериалов, которые к нему относятся

```java
public class Genre{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Serial> serials;

}
```

Пишу такой SQL

```
select s.id, s.name, s.description, sg.genre_id from serial s
join serial_genre sg on s.id = sg.serial_id
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, что я хочу получить. На уровне dao для сериала, нужен метод findAll.
В поля имя и описание будет заполнены полностью, а вот объект жанра будет одержать только соответствующий ему id. Что бы уже на уровне сервиса можно было вызвать два dao для сериала и жанра и по id записать туда соответствующие имя.
Собственно объект сериал должен выглядеть так

> Serial{id=3, name='Сериал 3', description='Описания сериала 3', genres=[Genre{id=1, name=null}, Genre{id=4, name=null}]}

Ну и на выходе коллекция из 4 сериалов в данном случае. Как через resultSet мне из 11 строк в данном случае, правильно создать 4 объекта?

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как должно вот такое сработать:

```
SELECT s.name, group_concat(sg.genre_id) as genres from serial s
JOIN serial_genre sg on s.id = sg.serial_id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Выведет что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Онлайн пример тут: 
https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle=5e5020d7fee7ddcik6wi9ydy

Comment: Как вариант подходит, спасибо. Возможно есть еще способы решит эту задачу?

Comment: @lost, мне думается, что других способов нет. Вы можете либо получить ту выдачу, что у вас в вопросе и программно её преобразовать в нужную структуру или получить что-то аналогичное выдаче в ответе и также программно преобразовывать в нужную структуру.

Comment: Вот я не могу придумать как мне программно преобразовать ту выдачу, что у меня в вопросе в нужную структура. С Вашим вариантом понимаю как это сделать. Может сможете подсказать как это сделать в первом случае?

Comment: @lost, наверное можно как-то так: бежим циклом по вашей выдаче, проверяем не создали ли мы уже объект сериала с заданным ID. Если нет - создаём сериал с жанром. Если да - добавляем жанр в уже созданный сериал.